# Extract string upto certain character

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

I need to extract string upto certain word
I have time like this :`"2012-12-29T00:00:00"` how can I extract the part upto `TO`.That is I dont need time.This string is not static .I mean it changes like "2013-01-21T00:00:00"

Comment: Show what you have tried. You can do a range search for "T0" and then get the string to that point. But using string routines is probably not a good solution if you want the date or a portion of it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use functions of `NSString` For e.g.:

```
NSString *string = @"2012-12-29T00:00:00";
NSString *newString = [string substringToIndex:10];
```

Your newString will contain 2012-12-29.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use like below

```
NSString *stingTime = @"2012-12-29T00:00:00";
if([stingTime rangeOfString:@"T"].location != NSNotFound)
    stingTime = [stingTime substringToIndex:[stingTime rangeOfString:@"T"].location];

//output
2012-12-29
```

Answer (score 0):

This should like this...

```
NSString *string = @"2012-12-29T00:00:00";
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"T0"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound){
    NSString *newString = [string substringToIndex:range.location];
    NSLog(@"NewString = %@",newString);
}
```